# Display a webpage while rendering

Tags: django, web, load, rendering

I'm putting together a website, where one of the pages holds an interactive map. The map is implemented as a big table, where each node is a td.

Now this map takes a while to render, and so, I'd love for the site to be displayed as it renders, so that even if the map is not fully rendered, the user can click links or the part of the map that is rendered.

Is there an easy way to do this? AJAX is one option, but since it is a Django website and the map depends on data from the Django template, AJAX becomes a bit unwieldy.

So is there a way to make the page visible while rendering?

(I considered making each node an iframe, so that they would be rendered individually, but that seems a bit silly too)

Comment: What is inside each `td`? An image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a few different things, it seems that the problem was too many database queries. Each of the nodes made calls to the database while rendering, which caused them to be very slow.

For reference:
Custom filters in Django should not make database queries, if they are used heavily on a page

Answer (score 0):

the django template should only render an empty map (or a map holding the first 10 points) with the javascript code firing on page ready

this javascript script should do this:

1. request 10 nodes from django (using a different url/view)
2. render the fetched nodes into the page
3. if no more nodes: END
4. goto 1.

Hope this helps

Comment: That might work. Seems a little AJAX-ish. I'll give it a shot